# etherpad ace_inner ios safari height bug

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, webkit, etherpad

I have this bug on iOS.
When there are a lot of letters in etherpad, on the next etherpad start height calculating seems incorrect - too big. This happens only on Safari on iOS, it's ok on Android.

You can see how it looks [here](https://youtu.be/n6nXOe0L1Ao).